# How can I find out if the target path for each symbolic link in the current directory actually exists?

Tags: shell

When I look at the last column of output of `ls -l` I can see symbolic links and the target path of each symbolic link.  Is there a command or script I can write to capture the target path and check for its existence?

Answer (score 2):

The following `bash` script will find all the links in the current directory and determine whether the target path exists:

```
for i in $(find . -type l -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1); do 
  links_to=$(readlink $i); 
  echo -n "$i links to $links_to and that path "; 
  if [[ -e $links_to ]]; then
    echo "exists";
  else
    echo "does not exist"
  fi
done;
```

**Example directory:**

```
$ ls -l
total 2
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     0 Sep 26 14:54 a_file
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    14 Sep 26 14:50 no_target -> does_not_exist
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff    21 Aug 13 14:50 has_target -> a_file
```

**Example output:**

```
./no_target links to does_not_exist and that path does not exist
./sources links to a_file and that path exists
```

The key commands are using `find` to filter out anything that is not a link in the current directory, and `readlink` to determine the target of the link.

**Note:**
Some systems do not have the `readlink` command. 
In that case, you might want to try adding the following bash function to the top:

```
my_readlink() { ls -ld "$1" | sed 's/.*-> //'; }
```

and change line 2 in the above script to call that function:

```
links_to=$(my_readlink $i)
```

but this is generally less desirable, since you are parsing output of `ls -ld` which is slower and more error-prone.

Comment: Careful with `-depth`; in only takes an argument in BSD find. GNU find requires use of the `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` predicates instead.

Answer (score 0):

in `bash` this will print all symbolic links without target:

```
for f in $(find . -mount -type l)
do 
  [ ! -e "$f" ] && echo "$f"
done
```